# Launching modal from content script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to launch a modal control from the content script of my chrome extension. This is the HTML for the modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ex1" class="modal">
            <p>Thanks for clicking. That felt good.</p>
            <a href="#" rel="modal:close">Close</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Link to open the modal -->
          <p><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">Open Modal</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm loading it like this from contentScript.js:

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('modal.html'), function(data) {

                $($.parseHTML(data)).appendTo('body');
            });
```

What happens is that the text 'Open Modal' is shown at one corner of the page instead of opening a modal control. I have added modal.html to my manifest file under web_accessible_resources.

Comment: You can't have tw `<html>` in one page. Either switch to a div (optionally with ShadowDOM) or use an iframe. And of course you'll need to position the element manually in the page using CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do it by appending div to body. Although I suppose using an iframe would be a better strategy.